# How to extract dll from the resource

Tags: delphi, dll, extract

my application uses Bass.dll and i added it to the resource. I wanted it to be extracted before the application starts it chrash. how to void it?

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers, I dont want to have setup etc. The idea is to make it instant, no installation requied to test the audio.

Comment: So you basically want your app to be its own setup. There are plenty of reasons that setup programs are quite complex (for instance: not being able to write in certain locations, even if you are an admin). Be prepared for a steep learning curve...

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers: Sometimes the users are teenager hacker-wannabes that fights the system and deliberately tries to mess up the software.  In these cases the "all-included-in-the-exe"-approach is very useful. Because you can check and rebuilt the installation at startup.  (Yes, I really know developers that struggle with this).

Comment: @Jørn: Good point. Never realized users could be that evil. --jeroen (who just found out that AltGr+L gives ø in your name on US-international keyboards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XBasic3000, I think your problem is wich maybe you are using a external declaration like this

```
function Foo: integer; stdcall; external 'bass.dll';
```

so the OS cannot resolve the address of the function in the dll.

instead you must use the  [LoadLibrary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions after extracting the DLL, in this way you can avoid crashing by checking for the existance of the DLL.

Comment: If you use the new 'delayed' feature introduced in D2010, it handles LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() for you.

Comment: i tried it but some of the function will not work spcially the Bass_Init.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the solution to your problem is described by [RPUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455468/how-to-extract-dll-from-the-resource/3455506#3455506) or [Chris Thornton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455468/how-to-extract-dll-from-the-resource/3458300#3458300) (both up-voted).  If extracting files to the hard drive causes you trouble, you should know that it is possible to load the DLL directly from memory instead.

Zarko Gajic explains at [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-load-resource-dll-into-memory.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you extract the DLL, where do you put it?  Your app isn't a setup app (setup.exe) which would have special privleges, so it cannot write to \windows\system32 or even \program files\yourapp under Vista/Windows7.  Attempting to put it into the program directory will result in it being located elsewhere, via the VirtualStore.  So you must verify FileExists('bass.dll') prior to attempting LoadLibrary().

Comment: on the current path. I dont want to have setup etc. The idea is to make it instant, no installation requied to test the audio.

Comment: Well if the "current path" is anywhere inside of \program files on Vista or Windows7  (or the x86 variant of the path on 64-bit systems), the file won't actually be there.